How to use import and return a value in the same eval?
I need to get the interpreted result of a simple statement that relies on an import:
strings.TrimSpace(" foo ")

In Yaegi, I could
_, err := i.Eval(`import "strings"`)
v, err := i.Eval(`strings.TrimSpace(" foo "`))

and obtain the result vom v.
I cannot however do this in a single eval:
v, err := i.Eval(`
    import "strings"
    strings.TrimSpace(" foo ")
`)

does not compile in Yaegi and
v, err := i.Eval(`
    import "strings"
    var res = strings.TrimSpace(" foo ")
`)

does not return a result. Same with wrapping the assignment in a main() function.
How can I obtain the result in a single Eval()?

Try to define a function that encapsulates the logic and returns result:
v, err := i.Eval(`
    import "strings"
    func trim(s string) string {
        return strings.TrimSpace(s)
    }
    trim(" foo ")
`)


I'd have to try this- but it's still invalid Go so likely won't work.
